# Enhancing the effect of Crescendo/Diminuendo in musescore

Tags: dynamics, musescore

I just want to know how can I steep the gradient of crescendo (or diminuendo) effect in Musescore?
In normal situations it's like there are no effects at all.
I'm using Musescore 3.2.

Comment: Are you trying to enhance the visual effect (hairpin size, etc.) or the volume effect? If you mean the latter, then a crescendo/diminuendo does nothing without dynamics flanking it (hidden or not).

Comment: I've also added dynamics before hairpin but finally changing the velocity parameter in inspector for the hairpin does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Just found the answer.Actually I needed to change `Hairpin` parameters in the inspector for the hairpin.Furthermore, dynamics besides the hairpin is necessary as others pointed out.
 [image: Velocity options in inspectors]

Also `Exponential` Dynamics method makes the effect more audible and less gradual.